# To breathe the purest air

Tags: riddle, homophone

> To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?
>   To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?
>   To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?
>   I'll tell you what - *me.*

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?

> bow -- as in bend forward at the waist

To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?

> bough -- as in a tree branch, from which one might make a bow

or

> bow -- as in a weapon made to propel an arrow (but this isn't a homophone)

To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?

> bow -- as the bow of a sailing ship.  This is actually downwind, so the kitchen is there.

I'll tell you what - me.

Comment: Not quite. I'm all sorts of confused on the third line explanation. Your second line coincidentally is in the right subject area.

Comment: @anodyne My third line is a bit archaic.  In a sailing vessel, the wind is faster than the ship, so the odors go forward.  Thus, the kitchen, which has smoke and perhaps bad odors from some food, goes in the bow.  A more modern, powered ship goes faster than the wind, so the kitchen goes in the stern (or gets things routed to a smokestack).

Comment: Color me impressed. I like it but would've never thought of it. +1

Comment: @anodyne  I wouldn't have thought of it either, except for having read "The Voyage of the Dawn Treader" (one of the "Chronicles of Narnia") by C. S. Lewis.  It becomes a key point in one incident.

Comment: I've changed my mind - going to accept this. My intended answers were 3 different homophones, but these words fit well and have at least one homophone, so all the rules were followed. Plus it's as good, if not better, than the intended answer. Well done!

Answer (score 13):

To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?

> knocks -- on the door

To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?

> nocks -- to keep the arrow on her bowstring

To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?

> NOx -- meaning oxides of nitrogen, which are pollutants

Comment: This is the intended answer. Note that this answer was posted *before* I spoiled it in the comments, and *after* I accepted an answer above. I'm not going to retract my check-mark above, but know that you get brownie points for this, @Ben J!

Comment: I only beat your answer by 10 seconds.  That was a close one!

Answer (score 9):

To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?

> Meet - You meet someone then greet them

To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?

> Mete - Having a good measure of distance/angle would allow straight shooting

To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?

> Meat - The amount of livestock produced for food is contributing to the CO2 in the atmosphere

Comment: Almost fits perfectly, but I'm not 100% sold on the second word. I would've written "do beforehand" instead of "have". I like where you're at on the third word, but I'm thinking a bit more direct. :)

Answer (score 9):

How about the word:

> Stand

*To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?*

> Stands up

*To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?*

> A stand for her gun or camera

*To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?*

> A taxi or bus stand, where the air will be polluted with exhaust fumes

Comment: Wow, great find. My intended answers were homophones but this works if it were a homonyms riddle. Nice answer regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the proposed answers are well-thought out and fit all the rules of the riddle, so I accepted one, even though it was not what I was thinking. My intended answers were:

*To prepare for a cordial greeting, what does she do?*

> Knocks, i.e. on a door

*To shoot as straight as she can, what does she have?*

> Nocks, i.e. on the bow to line up the arrow

*To breathe the purest air, what does she avoid?*

> NOx, i.e the family of air-pollutant nitrogen oxides

*I'll tell you what - me.*

Note the grammar structure in the first line that required the use of "she" (or "he") rather than, say, "you or "people".

Comment: If you wanted to make your riddle gender-free, then you could have used the formal pronoun 'one', or the generic 'you'

Comment: "One" would've worked great, you're right